# Getting Errors when I cancel a Sagepay Payment. Integration with woocommerce

Tags: opayo

I am using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sagepay-server-gateway-for-woocommerce/) to integrate woocommerce with sagepay server inframe. It is able to place orders however if I press cancel on the order then I get the following error.

```
HTTP Status Code:   500
HTTP Status Message:    The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.
Error Code :    5003
Error Description : Internal server error.
```

Is it possible to fix this. I am trying to figure out whether this is to with the plugin or perhaps the sagepay protocol

Some code from the plugin reads

```
$sd_arg['VPSProtocol']          = 3.00;
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: yes ... I can't remember now but almost sure it had nothing to do with the code ... certain it was to do with the settings somewhere but I can't remember where ... it might have been that my local development IP wasn't in mysagepay ... I think that might have been it ... otherwise it might have been that that server was set to live instead of test ( or visa versa )